# is it possible to conditionally right align an element using CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to left align B and then right align C only if there is space, if there is not enough space, how do I make just position itself after B instead of right aligning? is this only doable with javascript or can I do it from CSS?

```
<div class='A'>
    <div class='B'/>
    <div class='C'/>
<div>
```

I actually have it working using javascript to apply css classes and update based on those, but I was wondering if it was possible without doing that.

Comment: You can also use flexbox with `justify-content: "space-between"`, it will automatically align  based on space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flexbox`. By using `justify-content:space-between;` items takes space in between of them

```css
.A{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out `display: flex`

like this:

```
<div class=‚flex a‘>
  <div class=‚b‘></div>
  <div class=‚spacer‘></div>
  <div class=‚c‘></div>
</div>
```

And use this CSS

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto
}
```

For more information how flex works look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use

```
 flex-wrap: wrap;
```

remove display flex in your style

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23610513)

Comment: what do you means my anser is correct in place of text-align you gan use float left or right